# ios-Facebook login delegate method isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, delegates

The goal is to jump to anotherViewController after user logged in but stay the original page when user cancelled the authorization. I tried to use delegate method but doesn't work. I probably don't fully understand how delegate works in Facebook SDK I think. I set appDelegate properly because the Facebook button works fine. Much appreciated for helping since I've been struggling this for a long time! :)

---

```
//  MainViewController.h
#import  <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AnotherViewController.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *FBButton;


@end
```

---

```
//MainViewController.m

#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController () <FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate>

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set the delegate to self in order for the delegate protocol methods to be notified
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginBtn = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginBtn.delegate = self;

 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
        UIViewController *secondCV = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherViewController"];

        [self presentViewController:secondCV animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error{
    if(!error){
        NSLog(@"You've Logged in");
        NSLog(@"%@", result);

       //I want to go to anotherViewController after they log in
        AnotherViewController *secondVC = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController: secondVC animated:YES completion: nil];

    }
}

-(void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{

}
```

Comment: It asks the information of email, friends and profile and it gets better. It still goes back to MainViewController page though.... I want it to jump into AnotherViewController. Thank you still David :)

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem is now. Since I declared another new FBButton in my .m file, and I set that (in this case, loginBtn) as delegate. Instead, I should set FBButton I declared in .h file

```
self.FBButton.delegate = self;
```

That solved the problem. Wish this could help.